# Merging two Scala Future[List]

Tags: scala, future

I need to combine two Future[List] into one and I came up with the following solution:

```
    def mergeFutureLists[X]( fl1: Future[List[X]], fl2: Future[List[X]] ): Future[List[X]] =
    {
        val lf = List( fl1, fl2 )
        val fll = Future.sequence( lf )
        return fll.map{ x => x.flatMap{ el => el } }
    }
```

It does what I want but is it the right way to proceed?

Comment: Just a comment: Don't use return in scala

Answer (score 11):

You can wait for the results then combine those into a list:

```
def mergeFutureLists[X]( fl1: Future[List[X]], fl2: Future[List[X]] ) = {
  for{
    f1Res <- fl1
    f2Res <- fl2
  } yield (f1Res ::: f2Res)
}
```

Comment: Well, I was wrong, it gives you a list of results and not a new Future list. Are you sure, you need a new Future list and not the results?

Comment: Yes, I really need a Future[List]

Answer (score 9):

You could also use `Future.reduce`:

```
def mergeFutureLists[X]( fl1: Future[List[X]], fl2: Future[List[X]]) = {
  Future.reduce(List(fl1, fl2))(_ ++ _)
}
```

Or, for an arbitrary number of future lists:

```
def mergeFutureLists[X](fl: Future[List[X]]*): Future[List[X]] = {
  Future.reduce(fl)(_ ++ _)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to combine just two `List`s is probably with `zip`:

```
def mergeFutureLists[X](fl1: Future[List[X]], 
                        fl2: Future[List[X]]): Future[List[X]] = 
  fl1 zip fl2 map Function.tupled(_ ++ _)
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>I don't fully understand what you mean with "right" but</del> it seems you are sequencing the futures. A more generic signature for:

```
def mergeFutureLists[X](fl1: Future[List[X]], fl2: Future[List[X]]): Future[List[X]]
```

could be:

```
def mergeFutureLists[X](fl: Future[List[X]]*): Future[List[X]]
```

and your implementation could be expressed with `fold` as:

```
  def mergeFutureLists[X](fl: Future[List[X]]*): Future[List[X]] = 
        Future.fold(fl)(List.empty[X])(_ ++ _)
```

---

**EDIT**

> How does it compare to the solution proposed by @Kolmar

We both are using the operator `++` (list concatenate) within the `Future` context. Actually @znurgl is doing that too using the same operator in disguise: `:::`. The only difference of our 3 implementations is how we get into *that* context, using: `for-comprehension`, `zip` or `fold`.

I proposed an implementation using `fold` ([catamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism)) that works with any number of arguments, to generalise the example you proposed.

Comment: By "right", I mean that my solution looks rather convoluted and is probably not the most efficient way to implement this method.

Comment: I agree, the flatMap-within-a-map seems a little bit convoluted... do you like the implementation using `fold`?

Comment: It definitely looks better ;-) but I am not sure to fully understand how it works.  How does it compare to the solution proposed by @Kolmar ?

Answer (score 0):

If the types of both lists are the same, you can use `Future.collect`:

collect takes a set of Futures of the same type, and yields a Future of a sequence of values of that type. This future is complete when all of the underlying futures have completed or when any of them have failed. The returned sequence’s order corresponds to the order of the passed-in sequence.

```
val combinedFuture: Future[Seq[List[X]]] =  Future.collect(Seq(fl1, fl1))
```

Then you can just flatmap the two lists after the future returns